# SQL select statement - any keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a slight issue with a homework problem.  I am not looking for the answer, but I want to know how to figure it out.

Find the names and the phone numbers of theatres that do not show the movie ‘Gone Girl’

```
select distinct theatrename
from shownat
where movietitle != 'Gone Girl';
```

I only need help with the second part of the question.  How to find theatres that do not show a certain movie.  The problem with this is that if it goes to the second movie in the the Great Escape 14 theatre then the where statement becomes true and it provides it as a value in the result.  If I were in another language, I would just use a foreach loop on theatre venue and then just check the values.  There has to be an efficient way to do this in sql.

I'll give you a little bit of the sample data here.

```
Movie Theatre Names              Movie Titles
Great Escape 14                  Big Hero 6
Great Escape 14                  Interstellar
Great Escape 14                  Gone Girl
Great Escape 14                  Public Enemies
Great Escape 14                  The Departed
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      Big Hero 6
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      Interstellar
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      District 9
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      A Perfect Getaway
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      Away We Go
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      Up
AMC Newport On The Levee 20      The Departed
```

Comment: Tip: `not like '%the text you dont want here%'` :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos: This will give all non-Gone-Girl movies in theatres that do play Gone Girl as well. The OP explicitly describes that scenario as one which they don't want.

Comment: [SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: @Amadan I know that, it is just a tip so OP can find out the rest of the statement.

Comment: You already got correct answer by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have 2 base tables: theatres and shownat

If all theatrename exists in shownat table, the author already got best SQL:

```
SELECT distinct theatrename
FROM shownat
WHERE movietitle != 'Gone Girl';
```

However if some theatrename not exits in shownat, the following SQL is correct:

```
SELECT theatrename
FROM theatres
WHERE theatrename NOT IN (
    SELECT theatrename 
    FROM shownat
    WHERE movietitle = 'Gone Girl'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many responders seem to be missing the point. If you simply take the query in OP's question, or any of the variations provided by Erik, SIDU, Jorge Campos, you will also be getting theatre names which show Gone Girl and another movie, which is *not* what OP wants.

The answer is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT theatrename
FROM shownat SN1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT theatrename
  FROM shownat SN2
  WHERE SN1.theatrename = SN2.theatrename
  AND SN2.movietitle = 'Gone Girl'
);
```

"Give me all the cinemas such that it is not the case that in those cinemas there is Gone Girl." (SQL is untested, so possibly wrong in details, but conceptually solid).

There is several other ways you could go with that, all of which involve subqueries: "find all theatres such that count of movies where title is not Gone Girl is zero", for example.

BTW, ideally you would be normalising your table, so you'd have a `theatres` table (with an ID), and `movies` table (with an ID), and `screenings` table (with `movie_id` and `theatre_id`); this changes the answer a bit, but is better for you in the long run.

Comment: I do have it normalized like this actually, but left it out because all relevant data is in what you call the screenings table and what i called shownat.  Only difference is I used names instead of id's.  I can make this change.  Thank you for your help.